# Making a page where each user has his own information,gridview etc

Tags: c#, asp.net

After the user logged in , I need a page where each registered user has his own gridview and controls binded to his gridview.
The page will contain a sqldatasource binded to the gridview .

I thought about making a new table in the database for each user and in the form load to get the username after the user logged in, get the table name and replace the sqldatasource bind to his table name and the other controls fields for table name to his one.

Or is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: this is not Logical to create a table for each user,save all user information in a table is better and faster

Comment: Yes but I need a gridview for each user and the user must add new rows in it and ..where do I save them?

Comment: for this your can make a table for user in formation with a user id, and another table for user data entery.and make a relation ship between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely *do not* want to make a separate table for every user.  How on Earth would you plan to scale that to multiple users?

What data does the user need to see on their page?  Understand that a gridview doesn't have to map directly to a database table.  It can map to any set of data.  So you can store the data in your database in a way that makes sense to persist it (relational entities), then query and display it in a way that makes sense to display it.

For example (and it's a contrived example, since we don't know what data you have), if you have users who need to see a list of products that they've ordered, then you wouldn't create a table of products for *each* user.  You'd probably have a table for each of the entities (User, Product, Order, etc.):

```
Users
----------
ID
Name
etc.

Products
----------
ID
Name
etc.

Orders
----------
ID
UserID
DateOrdered
etc.
```

And since each order would have a list of products, and each product can be on many orders, that's a many-to-many relationship.  So you might create a linking table for that relationship:

```
OrderedProducts
----------
OrderID
ProductID
```

Then, for displaying in the UI, you would query the data to get only the products ordered by that user:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Products.ID,
  Products.Name,
  Orders.OrderedDate
FROM
  Users
  INNER JOIN Orders ON Users.ID = Orders.UserID
  INNER JOIN OrderedProducts ON Orders.ID = OrderedProducts.OrderID
  INNER JOIN Products ON OrderedProducts.ProductID = Products.ID
WHERE
  Users.ID = @userID
```

This should give you a list of distinct products ordered by that user and when they were ordered.  (Note that this code is free-hand, I don't have a database handy to test it.)

So each user would see their own specific information.

You want to make sure that your data is modeled in a usable relational fashion.  Define your entities (usually real-world things you're representing in the data) and define tables to represent those entities.  Relate them together in natural ways.  Relational databases are *great* at handling complex queries against well-defined data.  Don't try to design your database around the nature of the display from the perspective of the user, design it around the nature of the information being stored.

Comment: Well, the user is adding the "products" information in the gridview.

Comment: @Jax: That's fine.  Don't treat it like adding a full record to a table.  In the case of this contrived example, what the user is doing is "ordering a product."  When they submit the form for the order, the code translates that into a new Orders record and a new OrderedProducts record.  It writes all the relevant information (such as the date-time that the order was placed... the user isn't _manually_ supplying that) to the relevant tables and refreshes the page to display the new state of the information.

Comment: Okay but after I make the table , how should I bind the information for the logged user

Comment: @Jax: There are many, many ways to accomplish that. How do you normally fetch data from the database and display it to the user?  The question doesn't specify, at least not with any code.  In general, you'd get the ID of the user from their authentication to the application (however you track users in the application) and pass that value to the query as a parameter.  Then you'd display the results using whatever technology you prefer to display data.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly DO NOT need a separate table for each of your users!

Why don't you just add an additional **column** to one of your tables to store the username. This way, each record is marked to belong to specific user. Reading the data for logged user is just a matter of simple `Where` clause on the table.

Comment: Yes but I need a gridview for each user and the user will add new rows in it , and ..where do I save them? that's why I said separate table

Comment: You save them in the same table and mark them by setting this additional column value to hold the user name.

Answer (score 0):

No thats not right,
You can't create a table for every user. Think if you have 10,000 users than you mean your database contain 10,000 users.

You have to create only one table in which all user's information is saved.
You have to save an identity like user name or email to your database and
When user login to your app by his username or email the information will be taken from table on the basis of username or email and set to gridview.

May it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

this is not Logical to create a table for each user,save all user information in a table is better and faster
for this your can make a table for user information with a user id, and another table for user data entery.and make a relation ship between them

Comment: Hmm a table with user id , username , password , etc... , + the gridview columns?

Comment: yes a table for user in formation like userid,userbname,pass , ... but extra information can store in another table with same user id